# Set index as datetime: pandas, python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I have an original dataset which looks like this:[image]

I am trying to take the avgLowPrice out aswell as the datetime and have the dates as the index and a column of avgLowPrice. This is my code:

```
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data = df.filter(['avgLowPrice'])
data.set_index(df['datetime'])
```

and when i print data i get this:
[image]
So instead of my data being indexed by datetime it is just indexed by numbers 0-300 how do i convert 0-300 into my original datetime column to have the price indexed by datetime?

Comment: `.set_index` is not in-place by default

Comment: when i use inplace=True i get this: https://i.imgur.com/sRkarvr.png

Comment: Please help us helping you and provide a MRE (see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/14311263)). And [Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Make sure your 'datetime' column is a timestamp

Comment: @Nev1111 This is actually not relevant (it might be later, but not regarding the question here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your 'datetime' column is a timestamp first, `df['datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])`
Then set it as the index

```
df=df.set_index('datetime')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have either `data = data.set_index(df['datetime'])` or `data.set_index(df['datetime'], inplace=True)`. See the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html

Comment: Both times i tried this, i got a key error: https://i.imgur.com/sRkarvr.png

Comment: There is another issue in your code: when you `df.filer(['avgLowPrice'])`, the only column left is 'avgLowPrice', and 'datetime' is already filtered out. That's why you have `KeyError` as you see - it means there is no such 'datetime' column recognized in the program.

Answer (score 0):

you can filter with `data[['datetime','avgLowPrice']]` then `data.set_index('datetime')`

```py
data = data[['datetime','avgLowPrice']]
data = data.set_index('datetime')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your datetime column to `datetime` object first, then set the index using this column.

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
```

Comment: The type of the column has nothing to do with the question?